# jquery hide, show not working in chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, google-chrome

jQuery show and hide in developer tool and in `$(document).ready()` function it is working fine but in regular flow of program its not working in `expandTreeNode()` function.

Problem is only in chrome.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#loading_msg').hide();
});


//not working
function expandTreeNode(item) {

    if (item.p.postData.nodeid == undefined)
        return true;

    $('#loading_msg').show();

    //some code here

    $('#loading_msg').hide();
    return false;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is `//some code here` ? is it some kind of async function?

Comment: First, in your `document.ready`, put `$('#loading_msg').show();`. If you able to see it, i means it has no problem on `show`

Comment: @Kumar: I was facing the same issue, if in your code `async=false` then make it true. It would work in both - firefox as well as in chrome.

Answer (score 4):

Basically `.show()` and `.hide()` without any parameters would act as `synchronous` one, so try

```
$('#loading_msg').show('slow');

$('#loading_msg').hide('slow');
```

Comment: That's exactly what happened to me!
But I thought that's strange, because if I have a function that calls the load before the synchronous ajax, it crashes the application before the screen is updated. But in firefox it works perfectly synchronous.

Comment: This also helped me. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It may be that your JavaScript code is executed before #loading_msg object has been loaded to DOM. If you declare this function in your html head section try to move it to the bottom of the page or just move the function between $(document).ready() function.